# How can I place two controls in the same place and alternate between them?

Tags: asp.net

I want to place two datalist controls at the same (x,y) position. When the first is visible, second should be invisible.

How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle visibility of 2 divs. You then put your controls inside the separate divs and manipualte `display: block` or `diplay:none` based on whether you want to hide or show one control or another. This can be easily done with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which control you use, it only matters how you style the resulting page.  You can achieve this with [absolute positioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your styling, effectively giving both elements the same X,Y coordinates (but different Z positions, ideally) relative either to the window, the page, a parent element, etc.  However, this can sometimes complicate things in your layout.

However, if only one of the two elements is going to be visible at any given time, then I recommend just placing them on the page as you normally would, just one after the other.  For the one that's not visible, either set is as `.Visible=false` on the server-side so that it isn't sent to the client at all, or set its style as `display: none;` on the client-side to not render it.  That way both elements are available and just shown/hidden as needed.